# Save value and load value in Java

Tags: java, android

```
private static final String KEY_HOROSCOPE = "HOROSCOPE";
private String mHoroscope;
```

Given the code above, How to save the value of `mHoroscope` persistently ? and when saved, how to load the persistently stored value for `mHoroscope`?

Comment: well your first step is to chose a persistence provider brah

Comment: as always, refer to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in its current state, there is nothing that can be added that is not already in the documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use file to save the value of variables

reading from file :

```
File f = new File(Address);
FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(r);
String out = "";
String k="";
while( (out=b.readLine()) != null) {
    k+=out;
}
b.close();
```

so the String k is the answer

write into file :

```
File file = new File(Address);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(YourString);  
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value using `SharedPreferences`.

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // initialize the SharedPreferences, 'this' is a context
    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

// get the value for key (suppose the value type is boolean)
private boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
    return mPreferences.getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

// save the value for key (suppose the value type is boolean)
private void putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
    mPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference for persistent data when you close your app.
Create a global variable

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreference;
```

Initialize onCreate

```
mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

To store values:

```
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
e.putString(KEY_HOROSCOPE, value);
e.commit();
```

to retrive:

```
String horoscope = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_HOROSCOPE, "");
```

Or use Bundle if you only want to clear it when you close your app.